# How to "cross group" in a microsoft sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

I have a table. There are 2 columns. "Source" and "Destination"

| Source | Destination |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | DEF |
| DEF | ABC |

Now there are 2 results when query them by `SELECT Source, Destinaton FROM dbo.Pakete GROUP BY Source, Destinaton;`
But I want them to count as one. Like a cross combination from ABC and DEF which exist 2 times!

Example:

| Source | Destination | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | DEF | 2 |

Is there any query solution in Microsoft SQL Query Language?

Thanks!

Severin!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `case` expressions to aggregate by the smallest and biggest values:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Source < Destination THEN SOURCE ELSE Destination END),
       (CASE WHEN Source > Destination THEN SOURCE ELSE Destination END),
       COUNT(*)       
FROM dbo.Pakete p
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN Source < Destination THEN SOURCE ELSE Destination END),
         (CASE WHEN Source > Destination THEN SOURCE ELSE Destination END)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort source and destination to make sure that source is always lesser than destination. Now, you can apply group by.

```sql
declare @table table( Source    char(3) , Destination char(3))

insert into @table values
('ABC','DEF')
,('DEF','ABC');

SELECT source, destination, count(*) as cnt
from
(
select case when source < Destination then source else Destination end as source,
       case when source < Destination then destination else source end as destination
from @table
) as modifiedSrcDest
group by source, destination
```

| source | destination | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | DEF | 2 |